# Android Studio @CallSuper support annotation is no longer enforced?

Tags: android, android-studio-2.1

I accidentally dismissed the warning for the **@CallSuper** annotation via the **Alt-Enter** contextual menu and now I can't seem to find an option to enable it again. I've already went into **Settings -> Editor -> Inspection** and clicked on the **Reset** button, but it won't come back.

How do I bring back the warning because I really want to be notified if I miss an important super call.

Comment: Thanks for doing this question!!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you see what the setting for the `Missing Super Call` inspection is?

[image: inspection]

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I didn't know what the inspection was called. Also it's weird that clicking the reset didn't restore it to how it was. Thank you.

Comment: yep a bit weird I guess. Still, glad I could help you.