# Kotlin : How to remove super when overriding method

Tags: android, kotlin, abstract-class, super

I have an abstract base class that has open method for optional implementation.

```
open fun onBackPressed() = Unit
    
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        requireView().onBackPress {
            onBackPressed()
        }
    }
```

When using it in derived class, the method still allows calling of super even though there is nothing to do.

While you can impose a method for calling super using `@CallSuper` annotation, I need an opposite of it.

Comment: What harm is there in subclasses calling super if the super function doesn’t do anything?

Comment: @Tenfour04 just want to let them know there's no point of doing it and should not be bother.

Comment: @Sweeper yes, however there is nothing to import. Can you submit your answer? Will mark it later, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Sweeper Both `@CallSuper` and `@EmptySuper` is not present in androidx.annotation.

Comment: That's weird. Is there *anything* in `androidx.annotation`? If not, you should probably check if you have set up your build.gradle correctly.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, I can call `@NonNull` which is included `androidx.annotations` but no `@EmptySuper` nor `@CallSuper` exist.

Comment: @Sweeper just found out that it is included in 1.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`EmptySuper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/EmptySuper) is the opposite of `CallSuper`.

> Denotes that any overriding methods should not invoke this method, since it is defined to be empty (or perhaps contain other code not intended to be run when overridden).

Comment: Already used it, however I don't see any lint warning when adding super call to it.

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS You might need to turn on the inspection, [similar to how `CallSuper` has its own inspection that needs to be turned on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38195430/android-studio-callsuper-support-annotation-is-no-longer-enforced).

Comment: It seems there is no setting for `@EmptySuper`, all I can see is Missing `@CallSuper`